# Creating an array that counts vowels in a string

Tags: java, string, for-loop

I want to make an array to search for vowels in a string
something like umm

```
public class letstrythis{
    public static void main(string[]arg){
        String[] myStringArray = [1];
        String[] myStringArray = {"iwanttotryifthisworks"};
        String myStringArray = new String[] {"iwanttotryifthisworks};

        if(string=a,e,i,o,u;
                for (int i=0;i< string.length; i++){
                int intvalue = string[i];
                system.out.println(i);
                )
    }

}
```

Question, what's the function to search the string for vowels?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Couple things about your question. First, it's very difficult to read right now since your code is not formatted at all. Second, your code will not compile - it has lots of syntax errors and honestly it looks more like pseudocode than Java. At SO we help people with specific implementation problems - try coding an answer for yourself, and if you run into problems, then come back and [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We'll be happy to help you then.

Answer (score 1):

iterate over the array and increase the count when you see a vowel. you can keep all the vowels in a Set. There is no built in function to do this.

```
Set<Character> vowels = new HashSet<Character>();

vowels.add('a');vowels.add('e');vowels.add('i');vowels.add('o');vowels.add('u');

String input = new String("any input string");
int count=0;

for (int i=0 ; i<input.size() ; i++)
{
    if(vowels.contains(input.charAt(i)))
      count++;
}

System.out.println(count);
```

or with char array

```
Set<Character> vowels = new HashSet<Character>();

vowels.add('a');vowels.add('e');vowels.add('i');vowels.add('o');vowels.add('u');

String inp = new String("any input string");

char[] input = inp.toCharArray();

int count=0;

for (int i=0 ; i<input.length ; i++)
{
    if(vowels.contains(input[i]))
      count++;
}

System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: compiled it and the error
                      vowels.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
Set<Character> vowels = new HashSet<Character>();
^
  symbol:   class Set
  location: class vowels

Comment: You probably need to import the Set and HashSet classes. `import java.util*;`

Comment: yes, you would need to import. if you are using an IDE, that should automatically prompt you with hints.

Comment: i am using jgrasp, This is the program i learned on, i added    the import but still error.

Comment: and which version of Java are you using?

Comment: public class vowels{
public static void main(String[]args){
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
Set<Character> vowels = new HashSet<Character>();

vowels.add('a');vowels.add('e');vowels.add('i');vowels.add('o');vowels.add('u');

String input = new String("any input string");
int count=0;

for (int i=0 ; i<input.length() ; i++)
{
    if(vowels.contains(input.charAt(i)))
      count++;
}

System.out.println(count);

}
}

Comment: import java.util.Set; import java.util.HashSet;public class vowels{ public static void main(String[]args){Set<Character> vowels = new HashSet<Character>(); vowels.add('a');vowels.add('e');vowels.add('i');vowels.add('o');vowels.add('u'); String input = new String("any input string"); int count=0; for (int i=0 ; i<input.length() ; i++) { if(vowels.contains(input.charAt(i))) count++; } System.out.println(count); } }

Comment: The latest JDK and the latest Jgrasp version

Comment: imports are the first things in your code. even before the class definition

Comment: thanks! i will try making it with real time input and comment again

Comment: sure thing :) all the best

Comment: perect!feels good  import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set; 
import java.util.HashSet;
public class vowels{ 
public static void main(String[]args){
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Set<Character> vowels = new HashSet<Character>();
 vowels.add('a');
 vowels.add('e');
 vowels.add('i');
 vowels.add('o');
 vowels.add('u');
 System.out.println("enter the word");
  String input = in.next();
   int count=0; for (int i=0 ; i<input.length() ; i++) 
   { if(vowels.contains(input.charAt(i))) count++; }
    System.out.println("the vowels in your word are");
    System.out.println(count);

Comment: i would like to do it which char? can u help me?

Comment: public class Countingvowel {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); char letter;
  String sentence = "";
  System.out.println("Enter a character for which to search");
    letter = in.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println("Enter the string to search");
    sentence = in.next();

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
        char ch = sentence.charAt(i);
        if (ch == letter) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("There are %d occurrences of %s in %s", count,
            letter, sentence);

}
}

Comment: but i cant get it to be default characters like a e i o u

Comment: what is the error that you get? also, can please post your code as part of the question? it would be easier to read that way

Comment: posted, i dont get errors, this program makes me input the value to search for, i want to make the values stores not inputed

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Countingvowel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        char letter;
        String sentence = "";
        System.out.println("Enter a character for which to search");
        letter = in.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Enter the string to search");
        sentence = in.next();

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
            char ch = sentence.charAt(i);
            if (ch == letter) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("There are %d occurrences of %s in %s", count, letter, sentence);

    }
}
```

Comment: i want to make the values default which are the vowels, not input the vowels

Comment: so just use a Set to hold the vowels

Comment: is there any other way than using set?

Comment: ArrayList would be similar

Comment: ok, so you want the user to enter a string. then you want to check for the vowels. do you want to check for all the vowels and no other characters?

Comment: ArrayList<Character> vowels = new ArrayList<Character>();

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class CountVowels {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                    String string = "this is a test string for counting vowels";
                    int count = 0;
                    for (int i = 0;i < string.length();i++) {
                            if (isVowel(string.charAt(i)))
                                    count++;
                    }
                    System.out.println(count);
            }
            public static boolean isVowel(char ch) {
                    return (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u');
            }
    }
```

Comment: so the i is first 0 then for each letter it checks for the char values a e i o u? thanks alot!

Comment: i am glad my answer was helpful to you. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to loop, you could always use a regular express.

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

```
public class Regex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[aeiou]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        String s = "iwanttotryifthisworks";

        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

        int i = 0;
        while (m.find()) i++;

        System.out.println("Matches: " + i);
    }

}
```

There's a looping for m.find(), but it's not a bunch of loops.